# Change a number represented as an object to a long or other format within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-3.6

So I am working with python 3.6.5 and have a dataframe like below but much larger.

```
           Date     Open     High      Low    Close         Volume             
0    2018-04-16  8337.57  8371.15  7925.73  8058.67  5,631,310,000   \
1    2018-04-15  7999.33  8338.42  7999.33  8329.11  5,244,480,000   
2    2018-04-14  7874.67  8140.71  7846.00  7986.24  5,191,430,000

           Market Cap  
0     141,571,000,000  
1     135,812,000,000  
2     133,682,000,000
```

I am able to plot the different columns: Open, High, Low, Close

But unable to graph volume and market cap

```
df.plot(x='Date', y = 'Volume', kind = 'line')

TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

also when running

```
df.plot()

ValueError: view limit minimum -36839.658058149995 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

But I am certain that the df['Date'] is a datetime object

```
print(df.dtypes)

Date          datetime64[ns]
Open                 float64
High                 float64
Low                  float64
Close                float64
Volume                object
Market Cap            object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49927254/edit) your question and add the output of `print(df.dtypes)`. I am going to guess that the `Volume` and `Market Cap` columns are actually strings.

Comment: They (Volume, Market Cap) are surely strings. Numerical values won't be displayed with commas.

Comment: @Kevin My answer will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the `object` type columns, you can use :

```
df['Market Cap'] = df['Market Cap'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
df['Volume'] = df['Volume'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
```

Comment: I can't test but I strongly suspect that it won't. Does `matplotlib` abstract away the commas?

Comment: No, the type conversion to int/float is necessary. But the OHLC plots can be obtained. @roganjosh

Comment: But the question states "But unable to graph volume and market cap" so I'm not sure this solves the issue

Comment: I can add the solution once he posts the dtypes.

Comment: My money is on `object` :) strip the comma and change to `int`.

Comment: Hahahaha. Same here! @roganjosh

Comment: @pissall your solution of df[['Volume', 'Market Cap']] = df[['Volume', 'Market Cap']].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
 resulted in 

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Probably because they are an object, as my original question states what should i do

Comment: @roganjosh I am a little confused by what you mean

Comment: @Kevin (tags don't work properly on mobile browser) it's a comment for the answered to address. But you have strings, so you need a way to remove the commas, and then cast the whole column to some integer value.

Comment: @roganjosh I am actually using the brave browser on a laptop. Also I have an object not a string. When running the code provided by pissall it says that DataFrame object has not attribute str. df.dtypes says that both volume and marketcap are objects

Comment: I'm talking about my ability to tag you to give you a notification; I can't do that. I need to be at my PC to try test this properly

Comment: @KevinRiordan I edited the answer. I had tried it on a single column, so I thought it worked, but it seems it can't broadcast to 2 columns in shape